# Plesk httpdocs permission in skeleton

Tags: http

I would like my plesk skeleton httpdocs to have a drwxr-xr-x permission. Plesk creates users for each domain we create, but the only users that need access to the domain, are the developers who update the application code, and they belong to the group that owns all t / I tried setting it up in /var/www/vhosts/.skel/0 but the permissions from there are always overwritten.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Sergeys suggestion in another post](https://serverfault.com/questions/406336/plesk-adding-logs-folder-as-part-of-virtual-host-skeleton) I created an event that chmods all the directories on "Physical hosting created"
FYI Domain Created doesn't work, as it is being called before the actual files are created on the server.

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod g+rwx "/var/www/vhosts/${NEW_DOMAIN_NAME}/httpdocs"
chmod g+rwx "/var/www/vhosts/${NEW_DOMAIN_NAME}/httpsdocs"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, permissions and ownership are overwritten. You can only put custom files in skeleton. If you want some users accessing all domains on a server, you could include them in "psaserv" group, which is granted access to `httpdocs`.

Comment: hey Sergey. that's what I did already. my skeleton has drwxrwxr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 10 09:58 httpdocs but once a new domain is created it reverts to drwxr-xr-x. All the web developers are part of psaserv already.