# Plesk adding logs folder as part of virtual host skeleton

Tags: log-files

Is there a way of adding a logs folder as part of default Plesk skeleton? I would like to include error logging into a file in the vhost directory as a part of vhost.conf in /var/www/vhosts/.skel/0 but I don't want to risk the server tripping if the developer fails to add it to the folder.

I know that skeleton only accepts:

- httpdocs
- conf
- cgi-bin
- anon_ftp
- error_docs

but is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably code a simple script called after each new domain creation and putting your files or folder in  a domain. You can find more information in [Event Handlers](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-read-me-first/68703.htm) topic of Plesk documentation